# HTML Parsing and removing anchor tags while preserving inner html using Jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I have to parse some html and remove the anchor tags , but I need to preserve the innerHTML of anchor tags

For example, if my html text is:

```
String html = "<div> <p> some text <a href="#"> some link text </a> </p> </div>"
```

Now I can parse the above html and select for a tag in jsoup like this,

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(inputHtml);

//this would give me all elements which have anchor tag
Elements elements = doc.select("a");
```

and I can remove all of them by,

```
element.remove()
```

But it would remove the complete achor tag from start bracket to close bracket, and the inner html would be lost, How can I preserve the inner HTML which removing only the start and close tags.

> Also, Please Note : I know there are methods to get outerHTML() and
>   innerHTML() from the element, but those methods only give me ways to
>   retrieve the text, the remove() method removes the complete html of
>   the tag. Is there any way in which I can only remove the outer tags
>   and preserve the innerHTML ?

Thanks a lot in advance and appreciate your help.

--Rajesh

Comment: Which of the following solution below proved to be the fastest? Rajesh

Answer (score 6):

use unwrap, it preserves the inner html

```
doc.select("a").unwrap();
```

check the api-docs for more info: 
http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#unwrap%28%29

Comment: Note that if you are converting a fragment back to another fragment you'll want `doc.select("a").unwrap(); doc.body().children().toString();`

Answer (score 1):

How about extracting the inner HTML first, adding it to the DOM and then removing your  tags? This code is untested, but should do the trick:

**Edit:**

I updated the code to use `replaceWith()`, making the code more intuitive and probably more efficient; thanks to *A.J.*'s hint in the comments.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(inputHtml);
Elements links = doc.select("a");
String baseUri = links.get(0).baseUri();
for(Element link : links) {
    Node linkText = new TextNode(link.html(), baseUri);
    // optionally wrap it in a tag instead:
    // Element linkText = doc.createElement("span");
    // linkText.html(link.html());
    link.replaceWith(linkText);
}
```

Instead of using a text node, you can wrap the inner html in anything you want; you might even have to, if there's not just text inside your links.

Comment: +1 also note that instead of adding after the node and then removing it, you can replace it. link is an instance of Element and it can call the following method " replaceWith " which it inherits from Node class: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#replaceWith%28org.jsoup.nodes.Node%29

Comment: Good thinking @A.J. Didn't know that method!