# Joining HTML elements with JSoup

Tags: java, html, tags, jsoup, element

Is there any way in `JSoup` to `join` two or more elements in memory - i.e., in the `Document` tree, without producing the raw `HTML` string?

For example, the following HTML `div` element with some nested tags

```
<div>This is text with <custom>a custom nested tag</custom> and some <other>text within a tag</other>, all of which should become part of the top-level </div>.
```

would be transformed into

```
<div>This is text with a custom nested tag and some text within a tag, all of which should become part of the top-level </div>.
```

Essentially, the nested tags in the example above have been deleted but their content has remained, as if a string  `replace()` operation had been run on the raw `HTML`, before parsed into a `Document` object by `JSoup`.

The overall operation could be coded like this:

```
public static method splice(Document document, List<String> tags) {
  for (String tag : tags) {
    // Find the tag node (Element) in the tree
    // Remove the tag node and join its content with its parent
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `unwrap()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032677/html-parsing-and-removing-anchor-tags-while-preserving-inner-html-using-jsoup

Comment: Thanks and +1. If you put the comment in an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup's [upwrap()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#unwrap()) function is what you're looking for. It removes the element but keeps the children elements.